# Are regexp advanced filters in Google Analytics Site Content reports supposed to be case sensitive?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, regular-expression

When I apply a `Matching RegExp` advanced filter to a standard `Site Content > All Pages` report, the regular expression seems to be ignoring case sensitivity. The screenshot attached shows a very simple example - a search for 'Search' returns results including 'search'.

My understanding was that regular expressions were case sensitive unless specified otherwise. In Googling for answers I found lots of docs that say that Analytics regexp matching *is* case sensitive, but that doesn't seem to be true for me.

Am I misunderstanding something or are regular expressions in these reports not actually case sensitive by default? Is there a way of making it case sensitive?

Thanks in advance!

Dan

[image: Upper case query and lower case regexp matches - what's going wrong??]

Comment: AFAIK, the Advanced Search filter is not case sensitive (based on my own tests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Case sensitivity — Regular expression matching is case-insensitive.
```

*source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference*

**Solution**: export data (e.g. Excel)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I hadn't found that bit of the docs. I'm sure I found other pages that said they *are* case sensitive, but I can't find those now so must have imagined it.